# different color in markers google maps android

Tags: android, sqlite, google-maps

I have markers loading from sqlite db in my maps.
I want different color based on my sqlite db data to the markers.
But its not working. It's only shows 1 marker's color its red.

```
final SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM atm", null);

        if (cursor != null){
            while (cursor.moveToNext()){
                title = cursor.getString(1).toString();
                __global_endposition = cursor.getString(2).toString();
                String[] exp_endCoordinate = __global_endposition.split(",");
                double lat_endposition = Double.parseDouble(exp_endCoordinate[0]);
                double lng_endposition = Double.parseDouble(exp_endCoordinate[1]);
                LatLng endx = new LatLng(lat_endposition, lng_endposition);

                MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions();
                options.position(endx);
                options.title(title);
                if (title == "ATM BNI"){
                    options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ORANGE));
                }else if(title == "ATM BCA"){
                    options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE));
                }else if(title == "ATM Mandiri"){
                    options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_YELLOW));
                }

                Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(options);
            }

            if (!cursor.isClosed()) {
                cursor.close();
                cursor = null;
            }

        }
```

this is my db :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vAV8X.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use title.equals("ATM BNI") IN IF ELSE CONDITIONS

Comment: I have one more question. What if I change the `SELECT * FROM atm` to `SELECT * FROM atm WHERE atm_name = '" + pilih_atm + "'"` . `pilih_atm` is from the spinner variable that I've made.I want if I select "ATM BNI" only the selected shows markers in maps. Sould I clear the marker before execute the query? How?

Comment: you shold create an arraylist of Marker type and store the marker object in it and later on before you make query to db you traverse through arraylist and call marker.remove() it will remove the markers from map